# сортировку по алфавиту с++

Tags: c++

необходимо сделать сортировку  по алфавиту, 10 номер, сколько не пытаюсь выдает ошибку, врубиться не могу :(

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:212:52: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string’)  
212 |                 while (in >> tos) if (tos.category == it->first && tos.title == it->second && tos.category <= n) { cout << tos << " "; break; }  
    |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~
    |                                           |               |
    |                                           int             const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>
```

Объявление типа для переменной, участвующей в сравнении:

```
struct Toys {
    string title;
    float price;
    int amount;
    int category;
    int manufacturercode;
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Toys& a_o) {
        out << a_o.title << ' ' << a_o.price << ' ' << a_o.amount << ' ' << a_o.category << ' ' << a_o.manufacturercode << ' ' << endl;
        return out;
    }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Toys& a_o) {
        in >> a_o.title >> a_o.price >> a_o.amount >> a_o.category >> a_o.manufacturercode;
        return in;
    }
};
```

Фрагмент кода с ошибкой:

```
    multiset<pair<string, float>> un;
    Toys tos; Manufacturer mnf;
    Toys minA, maxA;
            for (auto it = un.begin(); it != un.end(); it++) {
                in.open(tys);
                while (in >> tos) if (tos.category == it->first && tos.title == it->second && tos.category <= n) { cout << tos << ; break; }
                in.close();
            }
```

Comment: много лишнего. см [mcve]

Comment: только, если это  информация о товаре, то оно может содержать их количество. Объект "игрушка" может быть только одна, поэтому его компонентом сделать amount, не совсем логично... Имею ввиду, что кроме  ошибок в коде, нужно заботиться еще и об ошибках в дизайне...

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим сравнение

```
tos.category == it->first
```

`it` — итератор для `multiset<pair<string, float>> un;`. Т.е. `it->first` — это, вообще-то, `string`. `tos.category`, если посмотреть определение — `int`. Т.е. вы пытаетесь сравнивать `string` и `int`. Ничего не смущает?

Во втором сравнении в той же строке та же ошибка.

Просто недосмотр. Стоили из-за этого сразу бежать на ruSO, тем более что посмотрите — *компилятор в сообщении об ошибке выдал вам ошибочный фрагмент, **подчеркнул сравниваемые значения и указал их типы***! Что тут может быть непонятно?